# Explanation with arrays and strings

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have found a code that shows the frequency of a character in a string. Specifically,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char string[100];
    int i, frequency[256] = {0};


    printf("Enter a String\n");
    gets(string);

    for(i=0; string[i]!=0; i++){



    frequency[string[i]]=frequency[string[i]]+1;

    }

    printf("\nCharacter   Frequency\n");
    for(i=0; i < 256; i++){
        if(frequency[i] != 0){
            printf("%5c%10d\n", i, frequency[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, I do not understand this:

```
 frequency[string[i]]=frequency[string[i]]+1;
```

What does it do? How does it behave? I believe that `string[i]` is the length of `frequency`? But I am not sure.

Comment: Where did you find the code?  Link?

Comment: Found it here [link](http://www.techcrashcourse.com/2014/11/c-program-find-characters-frequency-string.html)

Comment: 'I do not understand this' - it's adding 1 to something.  What it is you don't understand?

Comment: Beware of any code that is so old or so clueless as to use `gets()` instead of a safe(r) alternative, such as `fgets()`.

Comment: Original code has 'frequency[inputString[index]]++;'  Your line is different.

Comment: True, but since it is the same I was trying to rewrite it so I can try to understand it. But, I can't

Comment: @Akade I would be very wary with code from a site that suggests to use `gets`. Probably means that the programmer has been living underneath a rock for over 17 years. Given the use of conio.h, I would be guessing they've been under said rock far longer though, maybe 25 years. Now if this was a doctor teaching 25 year old methods, he would lose his job and the site would be taken down...

Comment: Here is an easy example. Suppose `string[i]` has `'A'`. So, the expression will be `frequency['A']=frequency['A']+1;` which is the same as `frequency[65]=frequency[65]+1;` (Character literals are `int`s in C). See [the ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif) to know where the 65 came from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, the *value* of `string[i]` serves as the *index* for the array `frequency`.

By saying

```
 frequency[string[i]]=frequency[string[i]]+1;
```

you're trying to increment the value of the `frequency[string[i]]` element by 1.

This can also be re-written as

```
 frequency[string[i]]++;
```

Having said that,

- **Never use `gets()`**, it seriously suffers from buffer overflow issues. Use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.
- `int main()` should be `int main(void)` at least to conform to the standard.
- It is a good practice to always initialize your local variables, like `char string[100] = {0};`
- [Link to the ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), for your reference.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible for you to give me an example of one iteration? 
Like how does this line of code work to count the frequency of a character

Comment: @Akade Suppose, the `string[i]` contains `a`, then, the `frequency['a']` or `frequency[97]` will be increased by 1 to indicate the increase.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand it now!

Answer (score 2):

`char` values can be used as array index. `string[i]` is a `char` and it is being used as array index in the statement

```
frequency[string[i]]=frequency[string[i]]+1;
```

So, if `string[i] = 'c'` and it's occurrence in the string for `i`<sup>th</sup> iteration is `1`, then the above expression will increment frequency of character `'c'`, i.e. `frequency[string[i]]` by `1`.
In this case `frequency[string[i]]` is equivalent to `frequency['c']` which in turn equivalent to `frequency[99]`, where `99` is [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) equivalent of character `'c'`.